# Problems filtering data and displaying it on screen in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming I am trying to filter through a list of data when I press the delete button and display the item on the screen where the id is not the same as the id I am trying to delete.

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" > 
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" class="container"></div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
const monstersEl = document.getElementById("container")
const list = document.createDocumentFragment();

getData();

async function getData(){
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    const resData = await res.json();
    displayData(resData);
}

function filterMonster(data, id){
    const monsters = data.filter((elem) => elem.id !== id);
    displayData(monsters)
    console.log(monsters)
}

function displayData(data){
    data.map((monsters) => {
       const monster = `
          <h1 class="monster">${monsters.name}</h1>
          <h3>${monsters.username}</h3>
          <h3>${monsters.email}</h3>
          <button id="btn" class="btn">Delete</button>
       `;
       const item = document.createElement("div");
       item.classList.add("items")
       item.innerHTML = monster
       const btn = item.querySelector(".btn");
       btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
         filterMonster(data, monsters.id)
       })
       list.appendChild(item)
    })
    monstersEl.appendChild(list)
}
```

I have tried filtering the element but I can’t get it to render the new item on the screen when I press the delete button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps!

```js
const monstersEl = document.getElementById("container")
const list = document.createDocumentFragment();

getData();

async function getData(){
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    const resData = await res.json();
    displayData(resData);
}

function filterMonster(data, id){
    const monsters = data.filter((elem) => elem.id !== id);
    displayData(monsters)
    console.log(monsters)
}

function displayData(data){
    monstersEl.innerHTML = ''; // Added the line.
    data.map((monsters) => {
       const monster = `
          <h1 class="monster">${monsters.name}</h1>
          <h3>${monsters.username}</h3>
          <h3>${monsters.email}</h3>
          <button id="btn" class="btn">Delete</button>
       `;
       const item = document.createElement("div");
       item.classList.add("items")
       item.innerHTML = monster
       const btn = item.querySelector(".btn");
       btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
         filterMonster(data, monsters.id)
       })
       list.appendChild(item)
    })
    monstersEl.appendChild(list)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" > 
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" class="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @OtonyeAmietubodie What did you do to fix it?